# task or new Thread(() working in local but not working in hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, server

I have this code in my web service

and register is return value, but  the Threed not working in hosting plase any help

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
        {
            try
            {
             //my code
                modelsonc.Email = userId;
                modelsonc.DavetlinkCase = true;

                var t = new Thread(() =>
                     user_link(userId,user)
                );
                t.Start();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, modelsonc);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ex.ToString());
            }
        }
   public async void user_link(string UserId, ApplicationUser user)
        {


        }
```

Is there such a thing that might have prevented the hosting company from reading some places

Comment: Tasks aren't threads, `async void` should only be used in event handlers and the method doesn't contain *any* `await` calls, which should be generating compiler warnings. This code doesn't work locally either - most likely the debugger kept the orphaned `user_link` method in memory before it got GCd.

Comment: `user_link` should be `async Task user_link`, and `Register should call it directly with ` await user_link(userId,user);`. The `catch` block should be removed and replaced with something appropriate - an error isn't OK. Sending the full error message to the callers is a security risk too - you're exposing your entire code structure this way. If registration fails, the method should return an *appropriate* status code (500? 400?) and a body with limited information. The full details should be logged

Comment: thanks for you,  user_link function can take a very long time ,That's why i want to run the secound function with out await

Comment: `await` doesn't block. That's why it exists - to await already running async operations without blocking. Don't use the thread, don't use `asycn void`. If `user_link` *doesn't* contain any asynchronous operations, just use `void` and call it as-is. ASP.NET uses a separate thread for each request.

Comment: If the operation is really that long (minutes?) you'll have to use QueueBackgroundWorkItem or Hangfire. Check [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) which explains why you can't just use a thread. In ASP.NET Core you can use background services instead.